# 2-D interpolation on an irregular grid in python

Tags: python, interpolation, geospatial

I am working with 2-d data that is on an irregular grid. For example the arrays will be longitude, latitude, and the data. The size of these are all equal and something like (100,90). The issue is that the longitude and latitude data are not on a uniform grid. I would like to get the original data values onto a uniform grid of latitude and longitude

I have looked into scipy's interpolation such as `interp2d` but from what I am understanding this requires a regular grid and `griddata` is for only 1-dimensional data points.

I have tried using `np.meshgrid` to create the new lat/lon arrays and it turns them into what I believe would be a regular grid with new dimensions,my problem is getting the original data to fit these new lats/lons

Comment: From the documentation of `interp2d` from scipy, the regular grid is not necessary. If you do not have a regular grid, you have to specify the full coordinates for each point, e.g. `x = [0,1,2,0,1,2];  y = [0,0,0,3,3,3]; z = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Comment: If you provide a small set of data to copy/paste (ideally input/expected output), we could orientate your choice towards the correct function/code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have uploaded the lat and lon to a google sheet. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PVkB2hV2l2GG8z8mAzd5E_5-GoGCHPSO4q4-OURhIGg) - lon [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rzo8tFlzoOF2_pnTy-0tZEQ6LP0mxJXwpbanF-rvAvw) -lat

Comment: My goal is for the columns in the lons to have the same value and change with the rows and vice versa for the lats. (e.g longitudes being x and latitudes being y). When using the interp2d I got an error `ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid`

Comment: I have no idea what you data is or is suppose to mean. As I wrote, create a SMALL set of similar data that you can easily manipulate and work with. No need to go to the real problem of long/latitude directly...

Comment: How irregular is the data? Random coordinates or regular but with a certain degree of raggedness?